# Is it possible to build desktop cross platform app(Same as electron) using xarmin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, electron

Can we build desktop cross platform app(Windows & mac atleast) using xamrin.forms. I know electron is already there, but more interested to know if the same job can be done using xamrin.forms?

Comment: Here you have the available platforms https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [Platform Specifications](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/wiki/Platform-Support) for Xamarin at GitHub it describes everything that you are looking for eg the supported platforms, are they stable yet or not and more.

In my understanding you are looking for:

> macOS || Preview || Microsoft
>
> UWP || Stable || Microsoft

And also if you needed it:

> WPF || Early Preview || Community

### Status

Early Preview - these platforms are early in the development cycle and made available for feedback on their viability and usefulness. Reported issues are treated as feedback.

Preview - these platforms are in some stage of development and reported issues will be addressed as time allows.

Stable - these platforms are fully supported and reported issues get priority attention.

### Supported By

Community - supported by the contributor and community at large, of which Microsoft is an active participant.

Third Party - supported by a third party organization.

Microsoft - the Xamarin.Forms team fully supports these platforms.